# How to give a default value for a property that is not set or equals to to an empty string in Ant?

Tags: shell, ant

I have a `build.xml` file like this:

```
<project basedir="." default="test">
    <target name="test">
        <condition property="foo" value="${foo}" else="default_value">
            <and>
                <not>
                    <equals arg1="${foo}" arg2=""/>
                </not>
                <isset property="foo" />
            </and>
        </condition>
        <echo message="foo: ${foo}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

How can I change my `build.xml` file to make the `foo` property equal to `default_value` when executing `ant -Dfoo=${NONEXISTENT_VALUE} -buildfile build.xml` shell script?

The `-Dfoo=${NONEXISTENT_VALUE}` passes a property to `ant`.

`NONEXISTENT_VALUE` is an environment variable that's not defined. 
I mean `echo ${NON_EXIST_VALUE}` returns an empty line.

`ant -Dfoo=${NONEXISTENT_VALUE} -buildfile build.xml` generates the following result:

```
test:
     [echo] foo:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

This is not something I want. I expected `foo` to be `default_value`.  Because `foo` is set, and I think it is an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ant, properties defined in the command line will always take precedent over anything in the script, so you're always going to have a problem if you define `foo` when you run the command like this. I would suggest using the `property` task's `environment` attribute to set a prefix for your environment variables, then reference the relevant variables within the script. Here's an example of how this is done:

```
<target name="test">
    <property environment="env" />

    <condition property="foo" value="${env.USER}" else="default_value">
        <isset property="env.USER" />
    </condition>

    <condition property="bar" value="${env.NONEXISTANT}" else="default_value">
        <isset property="env.NONEXISTANT" />
    </condition>

    <echo message="foo: ${foo}"/>

    <echo message="bar: ${bar}"/>
</target>
```

Running the above text, you'll see that `foo` is set to your user name and `bar` is set to "default_value"